# Updating Pandas Column Using Conditions and a List

Tags: python, pandas

This is similar to some other questions posted, but i can't find an answer that fits my needs.

I have a Dataframe with the following:

```
RK  PLAYER                SCHOOL    YEAR    POS POS RK  HT  WT  2019    2018    2017    2016
0   1   Nick Bosa         Ohio St.  Jr      EDGE    1   6-4 266 Jr   
1   2   Quinnen Williams  Alabama   Soph    DL      1   6-3 303 Soph    
2   3   Josh Allen        Kentucky  Sr      EDGE    2   6-5 262 Sr  
3   4   Ed Oliver         Houston   Jr      DL      2   6-2 287 Jr
```

2018, 2017, and 2016 have np.NaN values; but i can't format this table correctly with them in it.

Now i have a separate list containing the following:

```
season = ['Sr', 'Jr', 'Soph', 'Fr']
```

The 2019 column says their current status, and i would like for the 2018 column to show their status as of the prior year. So if it was 'Sr', it should be 'Jr'. Essentially, what i want to do is have the column check for the value in [season], move it one index ahead, and then take that value back into the column. The result for 2018 should be:

```
RK  PLAYER               SCHOOL YEAR        POS POS RK  HT  WT  2019 2018   2017    2016
0   1   Nick Bosa         Ohio St.  Jr      EDGE    1   6-4 266 Jr   Soph
1   2   Quinnen Williams  Alabama   Soph    DL      1   6-3 303 Soph Fr 
2   3   Josh Allen        Kentucky  Sr      EDGE    2   6-5 262 Sr   Jr
3   4   Ed Oliver         Houston   Jr      DL      2   6-2 287 Jr   Soph
```

I can think of a way to do this with a for k, v in iteritems loop that would check the values, but i'm wondering if there's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is much smarter than what you already have, but its a suggestion

```
import pandas as pd


def get_season(curr_season, curr_year, prev_year):
    season = ['Sr', 'Jr', 'Soph', 'Fr']

    try:
        return season[season.index(curr_season) + (curr_year - prev_year)]
    except IndexError:
        # Return some meaningful meassage perhaps?
        return '-'

df = pd.DataFrame({'2019': ['Jr', 'Soph', 'Sr', 'Jr']})

df['2018'] = [get_season(s, 2019, 2018) for s in df['2019']]
df['2017'] = [get_season(s, 2019, 2017) for s in df['2019']]
df['2016'] = [get_season(s, 2019, 2016) for s in df['2019']]


df
Out[18]: 
   2019  2018  2017 2016
0    Jr  Soph    Fr    -
1  Soph    Fr     -    -
2    Sr    Jr  Soph   Fr
3    Jr  Soph    Fr    -
```

Comment: I definitely prefer yours to my idea, i'm somewhat a noobie to python but why the underscore before season in the function?

Comment: my bad... the underscore is used to indicate private variables in classes. It should probably not be an underscore here. I'm somewhat of a noob myself :). I'll edit..

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to write a function that will accept a row, do a slice of `seasons` list starting from '2019' value and return that slice as `pandas.Series`. Then we can apply that function to columns using [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). I used a part of your input DataFrame for testing.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
    WT  2019  2018  2017  2016
0  266    Jr   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  303  Soph   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  262    Sr   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  287    Jr   NaN   NaN   NaN

In [4]: def fill_row(row):
   ...:     season = ['Sr', 'Jr', 'Soph', 'Fr']
   ...:     data = season[season.index(row['2019']):]
   ...:     return pd.Series(data)


In [5]: cols_to_update = ['2019', '2018', '2017', '2016']

In [6]: df[cols_to_update] = df[cols_to_update].apply(fill_row, axis=1)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
    WT  2019  2018  2017 2016
0  266    Jr  Soph    Fr  NaN
1  303  Soph    Fr   NaN  NaN
2  262    Sr    Jr  Soph   Fr
3  287    Jr  Soph    Fr  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't think i've seen the .apply function before and will have to look into it. If i'm understanding correctly though, even without passing the row to the function, it automatically iterates through the column you attach .apply to?

Comment: @EdwardGorelik Yes, it applies to each row or column (depending on `axis` argument) of the DataFrame.